# Accessing the Docker host pipe inside windows container with non-admin user

Tags: c#, windows, docker, permissions

In the last days I've managed to get working the Docker.net client in a Windows nanoserver container mounting the Docker's host pipe as a volume like in the example below:

```
docker container run -itd --user ContainerAdministrator -v 
\\.\pipe\docker_engine:\\.\pipe\docker_engine mycustomimage
```

However I've seen that to get things working I've also need to specify --user ContainerAdministrator otherwise standard ContainerUser user is used, and this not being part of the Administrators group the client will throw a "Access denied" type error when trying to access to the Docker Pipe.

The question is if there are ways/configurations on host or container to overcome this behaviour using non-admin users specially in nanoserver images, when powershell is not available and you are forced to use the standard cmd?

P.S. I use Windows Server 2019 without Hyper-V as host and Docker ee 18.09

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give admin permissions to the ContainerUser:

```
RUN net localgroup administrators /add "User Manager\ContainerUser"
```

This is easiest workaround.

"User Manager" Is a virtual Domain Controller that lives only inside windows container.

While "User Manager\ContainerUser" has "Well-Known-SID" it's not *YET* known for the host (Windows OS). So you cannot give permissions directly to "User Manager\ContainerUser".
But you can give permissions to:

- Everyone
- BUILTIN\Users
- NT AUTHORITY\SERVICE
- CONSOLE LOGON
- NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users
- NT AUTHORITY\This Organization

This is the list of well known groups for a host.

In theory you should able to map docker container users to host users by means of docker engine, but I haven't tested it yet on the windows platform.

Comment: `net localgroup administrators /add "User Manager\ContainerUser"
System error 5 has occurred.

Access is denied.`