# Non-root user not able to start w3svc service in docker

Tags: asp.net, .net, docker, iis

I'm working with the docker image "mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/runtime:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019". I've noticed that the default user for windowsservercore is ContainerAdministrator. If I try to run the image with the user ContainerUser (docker run -u ContainerUser mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/runtime:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019) I get the following error: ERROR: Failed to stop or query status of service 'w3svc' error [80070005].
I think that the error is related to the permissions that the user needs to run ServiceMonitor. So, first of all, is it correct to assume that windowsservercore images must run with ContainerAdministrator and cannot run with ContainerUser?

If the assumption above is correct I would like to confirm if running the container with ContainerAdministrator can expose the container to a security issue. As far as I understand even if the ServiceMonitor.exe is started with ContainerAdministrator the external-facing process is the IIS Windows service, which runs under a local account in IIS_IUSRS group. So even if an attacker could compromise the application it will not have administrator access to the container. Can anyone confirm if this is correct?

Answer (score 3):

I was in the same position you are. I can't confirm your assumption (though I assume the same). But I can provide our dockerfile which enabled us to run as non root (to comply with an AKS policy).

**dockerfile**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/wcf:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019

SHELL ["cmd", "/S", "/C"]
# username = '1000' so the k8s policy can verify it's a non-root user
RUN net user /add 1000
# We copy some config files in the actual startup.ps1 so we need write access here
RUN icacls C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ /grant 1000:(OI)(CI)F /t
# ServiceMonitor.exe puts some environment variables in the applicationHost.config
RUN icacls C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\Config\ /grant 1000:(OI)(CI)F /t /c

# S-1-5-32-545 is group Builtin\Users which contains user 1000. Allows user to restart the w3svc service
RUN sc.exe sdset w3svc D:(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SY)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)    (A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;IU)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;SU)(A;;RPWPDTLO;;;S-1-5-32-545)

COPY startup.ps1 /

WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot
ARG source=obj/Docker/publish
COPY ${source} .
USER 1000

ENTRYPOINT ["powershell", "/startup.ps1"]
```

**startup.ps1**

```
# ContainerAdministrators doesn't have these variables, but the
# custom account does have them. If this gets put into the applicationHost.config
# iis will try to write to the user specific temp directory, and fail (with an unrelated error)
Remove-Item env:TMP
Remove-Item env:TEMP
C:/ServiceMonitor.exe w3svc
```

Answer (score 0):

ContainerAdministrator is a special virtual account.ContainerAdministrator is the default account when you run a container – so if your CMD instruction starts a console app, that app will run as ContainerAdministrator. If your app runs in the background as a Windows Service, then the account will be the service account, so ASP.NET apps run under application pool accounts.

you could refer to the below link:

[Accessing the Docker host pipe inside windows container with non-admin user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56113529/accessing-the-docker-host-pipe-inside-windows-container-with-non-admin-user)